# no files in src folder of appcompat library

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

I was adding the android.support.v7.appcompat library to my Android project and found that there was no class in src!

So I went into the $ANDROID_SDK/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/src and it was indeed empty.

So is it supposed to be empty or am I the only one and if I am the only one then how do I solve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be empty. Nothing to worry. It a library with resources.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat

And to setup

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: so then why am i not able to import android.support.v7.appcompat.ActionBar and ActionBarActivity?

Comment: @hiphopdroid it may be bcoz you are doing it wrong. Follow the docs and it will work fine

Comment: Ok i saw the instructions and i was indeed doing it wrong. Sorry and thanks @Raghunandan